# JavaScript Isotope Plugin - "Trembling" of image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a demo using the JavaScript Plugin Isotope: 
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

The code:

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.2/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<ul id="crits">
  <li class="crit" data-crit="*">
    <a href="#">All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="crit" data-crit=".sports">
    <a href="#">Sports</a>
  </li>
  <li class="crit" data-crit=".abstract">
    <a href="#">Abstract</a>
  </li>
  <li class="crit" data-crit=".city">
    <a href="#">City</a>
  </li>
  <li class="crit" data-crit=".technics">
    <a href="#">Technics</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="gallery">
  <div class="pic sports">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic abstract">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic sports">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic city">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic technics">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic sports">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic city">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic abstract">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="pic sports">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#crits {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.crit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1.0);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 1.0);
  text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(250, 250, 250, 1.0);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}

.crit:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.crit a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1.0);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 36px;
}

#gallery {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

.pic img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var gallery = $('#gallery');

  $('.crit a').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $('.crit').removeClass('active');
    var crit = $(this).parent().addClass('active').attr('data-crit');

    gallery.isotope({
      filter: crit
    });
  });
})
```

Complete code and demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/WrxMjq

So far, so good.
But if you change the filtering by clicking on the buttons you can see a trembling / shaking.

Does someone know what's the reason and how one can eliminate the trembling? 
I've got no idea ...

-- UPDATE --------

I put the whole gallery in a div-container. Thanks to andyb for helping me with his comment.

In my CSS I defined a min-height. So the scroll bar appears **every** time and the "trembling" is prevented.

CSS

```
.wrap {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

If somebody has a more elegant idea then I would be pleased to read it.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding as I don't really see anything shaking but do you mean when you switch between "All" and "Sports" everything moves a little bit? If so, it is because there are more images on the "All" section which creates a scroll bar and pushes all the content to the left. If not, then I can't see anything else shaking. I am using Chrome on OSX.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I've meant and you're a right: This vertical scroll bar on the left is the reason. Thanks a lot.